# @RequestMapping não funciona no IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij

O mesmo código funciona no Eclipse e Spring Tool Suit, mas no Intellij Ultimate Edition não. Já tentei recriar o projeto do zero e mesmo assim nada. Usando as mesmas dependências e arquivos no mesmo local, criei um html para ser puxado pelo `Controller`, mas quando eu tento rodar a aplicação a página não abre ao digitar `127.0.0.1:8080/cadastro`. Estou usando Java OpenJDK 11 e a última versão do IntelliJ

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CadastroController {

    @RequestMapping("/cadastro")
    public String cadastrodefuncionarios(){
        return = "/cadastro/cadastro";
    }
}
```

```
Erro:
This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer essas alterações que dará o mesmo resultado que você quer.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/cadastro")
public class CadastroController {

    @GetMapping
    public String cadastrodefuncionarios(){
        return = "/cadastro/cadastro";
    }
}
```

Comment: com esse código ele não tá abrindo o arquivo HTML, qndo abro no browser aparece o texto escrito "/cadastro/cadastro", vc sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: parece que tem uns bugs que tipo eu arrumo a classe controler, dai pega, ai eu mudo algum valor e depois volto salvo como estava antes funcionando e para de pegar ahueaehuae, zoado isso, tá me dando dores de cabeça programar em Java, parece que em c# era mais consistente as coisas no Visual Studio